# how do I change the icon size in gnome fallback mode menu?

Tags: gnome-fallback

I have searched several hours, but did not find an answer yet:

changing the size of the gnome panel menu (the Applications menu that is provided by  Main Menu and Menu Bar applets, that is.) in Gnome Fallback Mode / Classic Panel (which is a fork GFBM)

in classic gnome, I can change the icon size (and thus the dimension of the whole menu, thats what I am after) via these entries in .gtkrc

gtk-icon-sizes = "gtk-menu=16,16:gtk-button=16,16:gtk-dnd=16,16:panel-menu=16,16:panel=16,16:gtk-dialog=16,16:gtk-small-toolbar=16,16:"

now I looked into the gtk-icon-sizes entry in gnome3/gtk3 documentation, and panel-menu=16,16:panel=16,16 seem to  be missing in version 3. putting these into ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini thus did not help either.

I figureed out that the style settings for fallback mode is in /apps/gnome-panel.css , but I did not see anything releated to size there, just color.

does anybody have a clue how to accomplish that?

thanks in advance

Comment: **ok got it** `[Settings]
    gtk-icon-sizes = panel-menu-bar=16,16:panel-menu=16,16  `

Answer (score 4):

As per your comment:

```
[Settings]
gtk-icon-sizes = panel-menu-bar=16,16:panel-menu=16,16
```

Comment: Worked Like A Charm... But it needed a bit of elbow grease :-)
I made a the following folder/file and added the above [setting] and got it to work. .config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini I bet I could tweak the interface even further using the gnome-color-chooser

Comment: I tried `gtk-button=16,16:gtk-small-toolbar=16,16:`. But it didn't work.The most annoying things in GTK3 are those big bubbly buttons & toolbars. Hoe can I re-size them? Using Gnome color chooser? Is it hard-codded in gtk3 widgets?

Comment: where exactly I can find this file?

Comment: @AyushGoyal `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini`